# Prevent collapse of flexbox div in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-material

I'm developing a AngularJS (v1.5) application using Angular Material and I'm stuck with the implementation of the layout. This is basically a fixed-height header, followed by variable-height content, followed by a fixed-height footer. The complete page should scroll (including the header) and the footer should be pushed to the bottom of the window when there is not enough content to fill the space between header and footer.

I've created a pen with the code I've got so far (replaced components with div's and introduced all the intermediate div's inserted by Angular) but when I decrease the height of the window, the content is collapsed to a height of zero instead of maintaining the height of the content and showing a scrollbar.

The problem is probably with the .main CSS class but I cannot figure out what I should be putting there.

The HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <!-- ui-view div -->
  <div layout="column" layout-fill>
    <!-- component div -->
    <div layout-fill>
      <!-- my own div around the page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-fill>
        <!-- header component div -->
        <div flex="none">
          <header flex="none">
            <md-toolbar>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                  <div flex></div>
                  <h1>HEADER</h1>
                  <div flex></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </md-toolbar>
          </header>
        </div>
        <!-- content div -->
        <div flex class="container main">
          <h2>CONTENT</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- footer component div -->
        <div flex="none">
          <footer flex="none">
            <md-toolbar>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                  <div flex></div>
                  <h1>FOOTER</h1>
                  <div flex></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </md-toolbar>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
header, footer {
  md-toolbar {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;

    .md-toolbar-tools {
      height: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
    }
  }
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
angular.module("app", ['ngMaterial']);
```

The pen: http://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/ZLwmvW

Comment: OK, just posted this and found a solution: remove the flex from the "container main" div and wrap the content in another div. I have updated the pen to include this change.

Comment: Another edit: changed the .main CSS style to include `flex: 1 0 0%` and `height: calc(100vh - 200px)` as this works on my test system but not in the pen. Need to do some further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex="grow" with `min-height` on container to achieve the desired result.

Here is the Code

```
<div layout="column" flex="grow" style='background-color:green'>
<md-toolbar>
  <div flex="10">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <div flex></div>
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
      <div flex></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<div flex="grow" style='background-color:pink; min-height:1000px'>
  <div ng-repeat="no in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
    <h2>CONTENT - {{no}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div flex="10" style='background-color:blue'>
  <div flex></div>
  <h1>FOOTER</h1>
  <div flex></div>
</div>
```

Here is the working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/NdVxZG).

Comment: This works like a charm and removes the need of the extra div around the content. However, the `min-height` needs to be set to `calc(100vh - 200px)` to take the height of both the header and footer into account.

Comment: You can use `min-height` value as desired. :)

Comment: You can use `min-height` value as desired. :)